# laravel 5 ->getRealPath() doenst show correct value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

On my local development I use the code shown below, which works perfect,

but when I uploaded the site to my shared hosting everything worked fine except my file upload. I already determined that the problem is involving
`->getRealPath()`, when I `dd();` that I get this path:
`/data/sites/web/christophvhbe/tmp`

Which doesn't exist on my hosting. But I found where the temporary images are stored on my hosting, which is in the `tmp/` located here: http://gyazo.com/e0199718324119109a4ff66321414e12.

How can I change the `->getRealPath()` value to the correct value?

```
$fileName = time() . '-' . $request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalName();
$product->foto = $fileName;
$product->save();

$imagePath = '/images/producten/'. $fileName;

$image = Image::make($request->file('foto')->getRealPath())->fit(300)->save($imagePath);
```

I'm using the `Image/intervention` package to upload and store images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are your account's root is `/data/sites/web/christophvhbe`, and that `getRealPath` is entirely accurate (what you see in FTP is likely [chrooted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)). As a result, your `$imagePath` is actually the problem.

```
$imagePath = '/data/sites/web/christophvhbe/images/producten/'. $fileName;
```

Or, better yet, use Laravel's `base_path` and/or `public_path` helpers so if you ever change hosting it keeps working if the paths change:

```
$imagePath = public_path() . '/images/producten/' . $fileName;
```

If you consult your error logs, I'll bet you find permissions errors trying to create a file in the server's `/images` directory, which on shared hosting you definitely won't be able to create or access.

Comment: what you are suggesting is the actual problem, public_path() and getRealPath are not accurate at all. 

the actual path to the image folder is : www.christophvh.be/images/producten/img.png . But that is not what it's saying, it is trying to acces a temporary map. which image/intervention uses to temporary store the original image i think. I know where the correct temporary map is, but i don't know how to access it, because it's higher up than my www folder. shown in the link i posted on top

Comment: So if i use your method i get this error:

NotWritableException in Image.php line 138:
Can't write image data to path (/data/sites/web/christophvhbe/laravel/public/images/producten/1434939947-thosiba.png)

Comment: Path and URL are totally different things and you should understand the difference. Using my method, you have the correct **path**. You're now getting a different issue, which is that the webserver can't write to the `laravel/public/images` directory. You can adjust its permissions to `777` with `chmod`, or if your host allows use ACLs and/or `chown` you can give the webserver access that way. Consult your host if you need help with that - what you can do varies from host to host. You should also consider getting off shared hosting if you're going to run Laravel.

Comment: @Chris If you took the 777 approach, please note that it's fairly unsafe on shared hosting - the other users on the server can write to that directory. Consult your host for help or get on a VPS (DigitalOcean is $5/month, for example) so you can be more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/to/directory"
```