# Laravel 5.2 UploadedFile realPath not /tmp but /public

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I upload a file to my API on vagrant everything works fine and laravel writes the file to `/tmp/phpLRJnhx`. When commit everything and pull the code on the live server Laravel writes the file to `/var/www/webdir.nl/public`. Why doesn't Laravel write the file to `/tmp/` on the live server?

Answer (score 2):

The location where uploaded files are stored can be configured using the [upload_tmp_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) configuration option. To check the current temp directory see the output of `sys_get_temp_dir()`.

Comment: `sys_get_temp_dir()` returns `/tmp` and not the public directory of my laravel project.

Comment: Please take a look at this answer [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970532/laravel-5-getrealpath-doenst-show-correct-value)