# Getting real path of input file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using `laravel 5.7` for my new project. I tried to read a input file without storing the file on project folder. For that i need to know the real path of the input file from the temp to read the file. Unfortunatelly i always get the path of the public folder : `"D:\wamp64\www\import-project\public"`, not the temporary path of the file so i can't read the file and here is my code :

```
public function importFile(Request request)
{
    $path = $request->file('file');
    dd($path->getRealPath());
}
```

Hope anyone here can help me to solve this problem.
Thank You

Comment: did you try to `dd($path);`, it may contain the information you need

Comment: what if you try achieve this using javascript?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970532/laravel-5-getrealpath-doenst-show-correct-value

Comment: @RayA I've got error message `stream_socket_sendto(): A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.`

Comment: try uploading smaller files, it is webserver error.

Comment: @RayA yes my bad, i forgot to setup the `upload_max_filesize` of the webserver. Thank You